# Created_at but don't group by user_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have an array of `items`. A `User has_many items`. In the `Item Index`, all the items are displayed and ordered by `created_at`, newest first. Sometimes users upload multiple items at a time, so in the index page it is possible to see items side by side from the same user. I have to prevent this. Really I need some sort of advanced algorithm, but I'm looking for something less complex for now.

To sum it up i need something like:

```
Item.order('created_at DESC')
```

but then do the opposite of group by user_id... in other words, order by `created_at` unless two or more items from the same user are placed next to each other, then separate them.

Its such an abstract question.. apologies if its not clear...

Comment: `Item.order('created_at DESC')` will not group by user_id. If a user uploaded X files at the same time, it is normal that it appears side by side when you order by created_at. Maybe you have some code in your view that detects if the current item has the same user as the previous item, and put them side by side?

Comment: Ah no, sorry, maybe I wasn't clear. Its quite an abstract question because I want it to separate the items if they are by the same user, otherwise go by its default behavior. I'll update the question.

Comment: so do you want to still display all items that are uploaded by one user ( in this case your options is to randomize it something like `Item.where(:created_at => Date.today).order("RAND()")`, or do you just want to display only one per user

Comment: You're right, RAND is probably best bet to be honest. I dont want to limit it per user. Basically one user uploaded very similar images and they are appearing next to each other and looking almost like dups, so I have to mix them up a bit. Thanks!